# what is a UPS/FedEx accepted physical address for the California Franchise Tax Board

Tags: california, state-income-tax

I need to file my California tax returns but am living abroad.
I was told that I can only use FedEx/UPS to send my tax returns, but the California Franchise Tax Board only has a PO box address where ever I look (which is not accepted by UPS).

Does anyone have an actual physical address  EDIT: incliding a street and number that has worked for them for filing a return (I don't have to include a check).

Thanks!

**Update:**

This address worked for me using UPS (and it arrived safely :) )

FRANCHISE TAX BOARD
INDIVIDUAL RETURNS
NO STREET ADDRESS
SACRAMENTO CA 95827-1500
United States
Telephone: 8008525711

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [FTB website](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/aboutFTB/add.shtml):

> Private Carrier Services (such as Federal Express, United Parcel
>   Service, or DHL Global Mail) do not deliver to USPS post office boxes.
>
> For private carrier or overnight delivery service, use the address
>   format below.

```
EMPLOYEE NAME OR PROGRAM AREA MS XXXX 
FRANCHISE TAX BOARD 
SACRAMENTO, CA 95827-1500
```

I'm not sure what you should use for the first line.

Comment: Thanks... i just edited my question: UPS requires a street address which is missing in all the addresses I found online

Comment: FTB is likely the only organization using that zip code. It's fine, really.

Comment: If the FedEx or other form requires a street address field to be filled, put "N/A" or "No street address".

Answer (score 4):

I googled "California Franchise Tax Board mailing address". The first link is [a page](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/aboutFTB/add.shtml) from the CFTB entitled "Mailing Addresses for Tax Returns and Payments".

At the bottom of that page it says:

> Private Carrier Services (such as Federal Express, United Parcel Service, or DHL Global Mail) do not deliver to USPS post office boxes.
>   For private carrier or overnight delivery service, use the address format below.
>
> Employee Name or Program Area MS XXXX
>   Franchise Tax Board
>   Sacramento, CA 95827-1500

Comment: Thanks... i just edited my question: UPS requires a street address which is missing in all the addresses I found online

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about UPS, but I've mailed my 2015 and 2016 CA returns using FedEx to the `PO Box 942840` address of the FTB, and I did get my state refund. Looks like FedEx makes an exception for the FTB and IRS.

Here's a screenshot of the address details I've used in the FedEx Ship Manager. Note also that the address was verified as valid.

[image: FedEx Create a Shipment FTB addres]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully FedEx my California State return by mailing it to the address-checked address mentioned above:
Franchise Tax Board
POBOX 942867
SACRAMENTO, CA 94267 US

The FedEx employees were dubious that this would actually be delivered because of their usual no-PO-BOX rule but it did work.

Interestingly, the return was ultimately signed for by
R.SHEPARD
9645 BUTTERFIELD WAY SACRAMENTO, CA 94267
also mentioned above. So this all seems pretty legit. FedEx was wrong about this PO Box exception!

Answer (score 0):

On the UPS website, I entered exactly as quoted above with the street address as " NO STREET ADDRESS". It told me it could not find the address and it may take longer than expected to find the location, I hit enter to continue in hopes they would find the CA Franchise Tax Board.
A few days later it was delivered to the address below and someone did sign for it...so hopefully this is the right place. I just need to give it a few days to make sure the payment went through and verify it was indeed the CA Franchise Tax Board and not something else.

Franchise Tax Board
State of California
9645 BUTTERFIELD WAY
SACRAMENTO, CA 95827